# Using named parameters after partially initialising an object

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm very new to Scala, so apologies if some of the following terminology is wrong. I have a case class with 2 parameter lists, say:

```
case class MyClass(a : Int, b : Int)(c: Int, d : Int, ... many others)
```

and I want to define a function which returns a partially initialised instance, where only the first set of arguments have been supplied:

```
def buildPartial() : **something** = {
    MyClass(1, 2)
}
```

and I would like to be able to use named arguments when supplying the remaining parameters, after `buildPartial` has done its work i.e.

```
val fullyPopulated = buildPartial()(c = 3, d = 4, ...)
```

Is this possible, and if so how can I declare `buildPartial` to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a partially-initialised class, so you will need to define a second class containing the partial data (I've called it `MyPartialClass`). Adding an `apply` method to this class makes it easy to create full instances of `MyClass`

```
case class MyClass(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, e: Int)

case class MyPartialClass(a: Int, b: Int) {
  def apply(c: Int, d: Int, e: Int) = MyClass(a, b, c, d, e)
}

val partial = MyPartialClass(1, 2)
val full: MyClass = partial(d=4, c=3, e=5)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use several parameter lists in functions:

```
case class C(a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Int)


object O{

  def buildP()(b: Int, c: Int) = C(1)(b)(c)

  val c = buildP()(c = 2, b = 1)



}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because `C` only has a single member, `a`. If you try to access `c.b` or `c.c` it will fail.

Comment: There were nothing about using b and c as fields of a class in question. So If you want to do it you can just declare case class C(a: Int)(val b: Int)(val c: Int).

Comment: There is sugar for case classes the all the constructor args of it are vals. so in case of using simple class you should declare class C(val a: Int)(val b: Int) if you want to use the args as fields.

Comment: So in my example b and c args are correctly used if used from inside C's body